# React Virtualized MultiGrid component skips first row in data set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a very basic usage of the React Virtualized `MultiGrid` component where I simply render a table of numbers going from 1 to 100.

For some reason tho, the first row will not get rendered. In other words, the table always starts at the number 2.

Here is my code.

```
const Container = {
  width: "90%",
  height: "100vh",
  margin: "auto",
};

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [],
    sort: {
      column: "",
      descending: false,
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      numbers.push(i + 1);
    }
    const final = numbers.map(n => {
      return {
        single: n,
        double: n * 2,
        triple: n * 3
      };
    });
    this.setState({ data: final });
  }

  cellRenderer = (data, columns) => {
    if (data.rowIndex === 0) {
      return (
        <span
          style={data.style}
          key={data.key}
        >
          {columns[data.columnIndex]}
        </span>
      );
    }
    const column = columns[data.columnIndex];
    return (
      <span
        style={data.style}
        key={data.key}
      >
        {this.state.data[data.rowIndex][column]}
      </span>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const columns = ["single", "double", "triple"];
    return (
      <div style={Container}>
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ width, height }) => (
            <MultiGrid
              columnWidth={70}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              cellRenderer={(data) => this.cellRenderer(data, columns)}
              fixedRowCount={1}
              rowHeight={70}
              columnCount={3}
              rowCount={this.state.data.length}
            />
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my output.

[image]

Comment: inside `cellRenderer` when you at `rowIndex === 0` you return the column names instead of the data itself

Comment: That actually makes sense, but then I dont know how to have the headers and the first row.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Doron's comment, I got it working.

Here is the code with the relevant changes.

```
const Container = {
  width: "90%",
  height: "100vh",
  margin: "auto",
};

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [],
    sort: {
      column: "",
      descending: false,
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      numbers.push(i + 1);
    }
    const final = numbers.map(n => {
      return {
        single: n,
        double: n * 2,
        triple: n * 3
      };
    });
    this.setState({ data: final });
  }

  cellRenderer = (data, columns) => {
    if (data.rowIndex === 0) {
      return (
        <span
          style={data.style}
          key={data.key}
        >
          {columns[data.columnIndex]}
        </span>
      );
    }
    const column = columns[data.columnIndex];
    return (
      <span
        style={data.style}
        key={data.key}
      >
        {this.state.data[data.rowIndex - 1][column]}
      </span>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const columns = ["single", "double", "triple"];
    return (
      <div style={Container}>
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ width, height }) => (
            <MultiGrid
              columnWidth={70}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              cellRenderer={(data) => this.cellRenderer(data, columns)}
              fixedRowCount={1}
              rowHeight={70}
              columnCount={3}
              rowCount={this.state.data.length + 1}
            />
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that now the total row count is actually 1 more than the length of the data array, and then when indexing into the array in my `cellRenderer`, I index by 1 less than the current index.